# vb.net replace method hide warnings

Tags: excel, vb.net, replace, warnings

I have the following simple line of code

```
           oBook.Sheets(sht).Range("A3:" & letter & lrow).Replace("N/A", "")
```

but when the sheet does not contain the any text the excel application shows an warning  message :

"we couldn't find anything to replace ..."

Is there a way to avoid this message ??
I already have tried the

```
          application.screenupdating = false and xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: What about something like `If oBook.Sheets(sht).Range("A3:" & letter & lrow)="N/A" Then oBook.Sheets(sht).Range("A3:" & letter & lrow).Replace("N/A", "") ` ?? Or check if `Range("A3:" & letter & lrow)` contains the string "N/A" and if true, then replace

Comment: Thank You for your answer ! this is a smart solution but the range uses multiple cells. I tried to use the find method, but i couldnt make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try this (substituting in the range values, and potentially the "ActiveSheet" with your "sht" variable);

```
Dim strReplace As String
strReplace = "N/A"

Dim strReplaceWith As String
strReplaceWith = ""

ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A15").Cells.Replace strReplace, strReplaceWith
```

Assuming you're doing this in VBA however, not VB.NET due to the screenupdating and displayalerts lines.

Answer (score 0):

And what about doing a loop and check every individual cell inside your range composed by multiple cells?

```
Dim RnG As Range

For Each RnG In oBook.Sheets(sht).Range("A3:" & letter & lrow)
    If InStr(1, RnG, "CA", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then RnG.Replace "N/A", ""
Next RnG
```